# RSA Encryption in java and python gives different encryption result

Tags: java, python, rsa, public-key-encryption, steam

I am trying to encrypt my password with RSA public key that is send by steam.

I have code in python that gives a encryped password that I expect and the java code gives a different result.

Here is the code in python :

```py
import rsa
import base64
import requests

rsa_mod = int("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", 16)
rsa_exp = int("010001", 16)
password = "password"

rsa_key = rsa.PublicKey(rsa_mod, rsa_exp)

encrypedPassword = base64.b64encode(rsa.encrypt(password.encode('utf-8'), rsa_key))

print(encrypedPassword)
```

The result from python :

```
b'P7VLrCteJCfoV4UELktZlDjjcQRRhLOcRhoqdd3H2rKe3KQpWPfBfMQZhxpF7NDoNx5KXDnXO7Ew9o87egxOUbAHvmckrorD4VQHNauoSjQR03ibxfNSMwRh8CJOOJVi6wykvijIPHuJBZtNI8XhgNYn8LJLz4jN37MJmocCi80oB/UCSsS3v87mUYo6Ik1xTmqiOxojRLzhw9Lfw1A33pEj4NfiwnLRjE7jd1evAtfgTUiOLXhaUv5J8PYTwzUmLZTft+8JsLEUzaYSfAxbL6M0s6s62dFCKmrAmrKtPwl8VD+6BlWCLdt1j2JNQuND+OZIpjyY7KadTGtCA8if3A=='
```

Here is the java code :

```java
private final String PASSWORD = "password";
private final String publickey_mod= "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";
private final String publickey_exp = "010001" ;

private String encryptPassWordWithRSAKey() {
  BigInteger module = new BigInteger(publickey_mod, 16);
  BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(publickey_exp, 16);
  try {
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(module, exponent);
    RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    byte[] encryptedPassWord = cipher.doFinal(PASSWORD.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedPassWord);
} catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
    System.out.println("Exception in encryptPassWordWithRSAKey method of LoginExecutor");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
}

public String getEncryptedkey(){
  return this.encryptPassWordWithRSAKey();
}
```

Result from above code:

```
SrA4QK2FXFIB/c5ZOuUJ+SZLTcgYyp3eWYD7TTo7krfiyRxbSekVQHAooBzL/k8/DQwbUxR5InUKHxAqUMZ9MU87H+ULXOGi9a0N/37ymTXBnqGna8XvjtnpeVG8h5PXilZdLqeGDdn5wuNNtN6+61rPsifYJy2M9BUdXIfs2EyS0LQixRkPcfQN4Qd+K6UPBLpc7D4SUkTMJSDgp7umZeifz+hEPmE+FYEBtmDf1uLFB4/B9srgyDxLXjFZS/gk27EYrtEuiPbR0pmZs75JCRFk0Y5p1wQEmgCujs3+PuJTXdyHdrO4fxqTGHzKZRau2zZOaT3RWoU/x/u8QSKfZg==
```

I have already tried to use Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding") but does not give expected result.

All the help is appreciated. Have a wonderful day.

Comment: For RSA encryption, padding (no matter whether PKCS#1 v1.5 padding or OAEP) generates a _different_ ciphertext for _each_ encryption (even for _identical_ plaintext and _identical_ key).

Comment: Yes I tried to do it repeatedly and the encryption result change every time, but I want to know if the two work the same. Python code generates correct password encryption and my java code does not. So what might be the reason for the difference? Thank you for the reply.

Comment: what python rsa package are you using?

Comment: Both codes seem to be functionally identical, since the ciphertexts of both codes can be decrypted with Python, more precisely with [`rsa.decrypt`](https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/usage.html#encryption-and-decryption), at least for my testkey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stopped working on this for a while. Got back to this and found that I was making a very stupid mistake. 
The Encryption is right. When I was passing password as the query parameter, I need to replace the '=', '+', '/' with url encoding. 
Reference from : w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP.

Here is the final code that I added :

```
String urlSafePassword = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedPassWord);
            urlSafePassword.replace("/", "%2F");
            urlSafePassword.replace("+", "%2B");
            urlSafePassword.replace("=", "%3D");
            return urlSafePassword;
```

I kept thinking that my encrytion type.

Thanks for all the help guys.
Have a great day.