# RSA encryption in Python unable to decrypt in Java

Tags: python, java, encryption, rsa, pkcs#1

I make RSA **encryption in python** with private key and cannot **decrypt in Java** with public key. Below is Python/Java source codes and exception.
I tried multiple combinations with PKCS1_OAEP and hash algorythms but getting the same error.

At the same time encription / decription **within the same platform** works fine (e.g. encrypt in Java or Python with public key and decrypt with private and vice versa encrypt in Java or Python with private key and decrypt with public)

Java version = 1.8,
Python version = 3.10

**Python**

```
import base64
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5

KEY = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" \
      "MII...WI=" \
      "\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

#import private key
priv_key = RSA.import_key(KEY)
rsa_cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(priv_key)
#encode text
enc_text = rsa_cipher.encrypt("Hello Stackoverflow".encode('utf-8'))
enc_text_64 = base64.b64encode(cipher_text).decode("utf-8")
print(enc_text_64)
```

**Java**

```
PublicKey pubKey = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodeBase64(PUBLIC_KEY))).getPublicKey();

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", new BouncyCastleProvider());
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pubKey);        
String res = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(str)), "utf-8");
```

**Exception in Java**

```
org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.util.BadBlockException: unable to decrypt block
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: block incorrect
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61388531/rsa-encryption-in-java-and-python-gives-different-encryption-result

Comment: You **encrypt** with a public key and **decrypt** with a private key. Note that the public key is included in the private key for RSA, so it is probably using that. What are you trying to achieve? @ᴇʟᴇvᴀтᴇ That's not a dupe, different issue.

Comment: Both libraries behave differently: Java, allows decryption with the public key (as part of a low level signing/verification process, where the private key is used for signing; as padding RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 is implicitly applied). Python, on the other hand, doesn't allow this. As described in the previous comment, Python encrypts with the public key contained in the private key (as padding RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 is implicitly applied). Therefore your combination is not compatible (public key for both, encryption and decryption, and two divergent paddings).

Comment: I'm trying to acive secure communication between client and server applications. On client side I use public key for encryption and private key on the server side.  
When the server side app responds the message supposed to be encrypted and client should be able to read it.
I do not expose nor publish public key, it is embedded in application.
Potentially I can switch public and private key between peers if the needful cannot be achieved with Python.

Comment: The correct way is for each side to generate a key pair and exchange the public keys. Encryption uses the recipient's public key, so that only the recipient can decrypt with its own private key. Encryption with the private key is not supported by most libraries (like PyCryptodome), because decryption with the public key (which generally everyone can have) for the purpose of confidentiality is a contradiction in terms.